# Create a column that counts the number of times a value shows up on another column, from the same table - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, counter

In MySQL:

Lets say I've this table:

```
id | name | count |
 1 | John |       |
 2 | John |       |
 3 | John |       |
 4 | Mary |       |
 5 | Lewis|       |
 6 | Lewis|       |
 7 | Max  |       |
 8 | Max  |       |
```

The names are already grouped, so the same name comes up together.
Now I want the table to be like this:

```
id | name | count |
 1 | John |   1   |
 2 | John |   2   |
 3 | John |   3   |
 4 | Mary |   1   |
 5 | Lewis|   1   |
 6 | Lewis|   2   |
 7 | Max  |   1   |
 8 | Max  |   2   |
```

Notice it auto increments the value of count everytime there is a repetition of the same name.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want that column materialized in the table, or do you just want to get that column as a result in a query/view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a user variable.

Something like this:-

```
UPDATE somepeople a
INNER JOIN (
SELECT id, name, IF(@PrevName=name, @aCnt := @aCnt + 1, @aCnt := 1) AS sequence, @PrevName:=name
FROM somepeople,
(SELECT @aCnt:=1, @PrevName:='') Sub1
ORDER BY name, id) b
ON a.id = b.id
SET a.count = b.sequence
```